# Purge artefacts with maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I want to run `mvn` command to get rid of all artefacts under `~/.m2/repository/here/goes/my/groupid`. In order to do so, I run:

```
mvn -pl my-module dependency:purge-local-repository -DresolutionFuzziness=groupId -Dinclude=<here-goes-my-groupid> -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false -Dverbose=true
```

This works fine, as long as the current version (3.0.0) of the current artefact (my-maven-plugin) is in the local repo.

If the current version (3.0.0) of the current artefact (my-maven-plugin) is **not** in the local repo (e.g. there is only an older version of this artefact in the local repo, say 2.9.0), nothing gets purged:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:purge-local-repository (default-cli) @ my-maven-plugin ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/here/goes/my/groupid/my-maven-plugin/3.0.0/my-maven-plugin-3.0.0.jar
[INFO] Unable to resolve all dependencies for : <here-goes-my-groupid>:my-maven-plugin:3.0.0. Falling back to non-transitive mode for initial artifact resolution.
[INFO] No artifacts included for purge for project: <here-goes-my-groupid>:my-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.0.0
```

I don't understand why maven-dependency-plugin tries to download anything from maven central. All it should do is to recursively drop a folder in local filesystem.

How can I enforce purging all artefact under given groupId, no matter if the current version of the current artefact is in the local repo or not?

Comment: What's the link with `my-module` that you're using in the command? `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DresolutionFuzziness=groupId -Dinclude=<here-goes-my-groupid> -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false -Dverbose=true` works as expected for me. Note that you don't need to launch that command from a Maven project, if using 3.0.0 of the plugin, i.e. `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:purge-local-repository ...`

Comment: When I run `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:purge-local-repository -DresolutionFuzziness=groupId -Dinclude=<my.groupId> -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false -Dverbose=true` from outside of maven project, it doesn't do anything: `Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/standalone-pom/1/standalone-pom-1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] No artifacts included for purge for project: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1`

Comment: What did you mean by "What's the link with my-module that you're using in the command?" ? my-module is a module in my reactor pom.

Comment: What's in your ~/.m2/settings.xml and pom.xml?

Comment: settings.xml:

<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
only credentials for releasing
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>

Answer (score 1):

`include` expects the `groupId` of the dependency being purged to be exactly same as that of the project.
The options `resolutionFuzziness`, `actTransitively` and `reResolve` apply only when the said `groupId` condition is satisfied.
I guess, this might be because the plugin developers want to prevent the accidental purging of artifacts that are out of project's group. It's my wild guess though.

Relax! `manualInclude` comes to the rescue. It can purge the artifacts irrespective of the project's `groupId`.

Try this:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude=<group-id>:<artifact-id>
```

or this:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualIncludes=<group-id>:<artifact-id>
```

However, the difference is that unlike `include` it doesn't re-resolve the artifact after purge, no matter what value you give to `reResolve`.

[This](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo.html#L328) condition skips the re-resolve.